# JQuery Full Calendar Header duplicated

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using the default demo the header gets duplicated. the only thing I can do is add header:false and than no header shows. Using files directly from download. Doing same thing with the other demos as well.
http://rcsweb.com/bagels/demos/default.html

Comment: I did a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9uA/1/) with the CSS and JS files from your site and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the `jQuery` core version: http://rcsweb.com/bagels/scripts/jquery.min.js

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UH2rm/

If replaced with a CDN version: http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

It will work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YDTnd/

Try to replace your jQuery core js file, maybe it is corrupted or served in the wrong way.

Comment: +1. Right, I just used the CSS and JS relating to the fullcalendar plugin alone from the OP's site.